# Error al conectar SQL-SERVER con C#

Tags: c#

Buen día a todos tengo el siguiente código para establecer una **conexion** a una base de datos **SQL-SERVER 2014**.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;

namespace QDoc.Acceso
{
    class Conexion
    {
        //variable globales
        private static string cadenaconexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion"].ConnectionString; // lee la cadena de conexión de la configuración de la aplicación
```

El detalle esta que al ejecutarlo me manda el siguiente error:

**El nombre 'ConfigurationManager' no existe en el contexto actual** ya use las opciones que se me dan y no logro corregir el error, alguien sabe que puedo hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes asegurarte de agregar la referencia al ensamblado **System.Configuration.dll**. En tu proyecto, dale click derecho y después en **Referencias** (References), selecciona **Agregar referencia** (Add Reference) y, ahí buscas System.Configuration.

Comment: Gracias amigo, esa era la solución, estaba agregando la libreria using System.Configuration; pero la referencia no existia en el proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate que tienes la referencia a `System.Configuration` añadida al proyecto, pues en ocasiones no sirve sólo con añadir la instrucción `using System.Configuration;`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no aparece, haz click derecho en la propia pestaña de referencias y añade la referencia a `System.Configuration.dll`. Recompila el proyecto y comprueba que todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias amigo, si ese fue el detalle que estaba omitiendo, saludos.